# Layer wise propagation(LRP) in keras neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, heatmap

I have been following [LRP](http://heatmapping.org/tutorial/) implementation using pyTorch and wanted to test it out using Tensorflow and Keras. I am using the same model with weights(VGG16) in Keras and was able to successfully execute the **forward pass** and **element wise division** using

```
# keras-tensorflow implementation
z = incr(clasifierLayers[l](A[l])) # forward pass step(1)
s = (R[l+1]/z) # Element wise division step(2)
```

But i am facing trouble in recreating the **backward pass**. In the original code([LRP](http://heatmapping.org/tutorial/)), which uses pyTorch, the backward pass is computed using

```
# pyTorch implementation
(z*s).sum().backward(); c = A[l].grad
```

and when i tried to find the replicate the backward pass using tensorflow, my gradient returns **None**. Here is my code trying to compute the backward pass.

```
def getGradients(product,layer,l):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(product)
        a=layers[l](A[l])
        gradient = tape.gradient(product, a) 
    return gradient

c = getGradients((z*s).numpy().sum(),layers[l],l) # backward pass step(3)
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with this implementation?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue with one layer and performing an LRP backward step, here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.ones((1,10))
layer=tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
y=layer(x)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
     tape.watch(x)
     z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(x)+1e-9
     s = y/z
     s = tf.reshape(s, z.shape)
     c = tape.gradient(tf.reduce_sum(z*s), x)
     y*c
```

This code works, in the sense that it returns the gradients to `c`.
I did not test it with a dataset, so do not know if it works as it should. Nonetheless, I think the problem with your code is that you should have the first block:

```
# keras-tensorflow implementation
z = incr(clasifierLayers[l](A[l])) # forward pass step(1)
s = (R[l+1]/z) # Element wise division step(2)
```

inside the TapeGradient scope and ask for the gradients with respect to the `A[l]`.

Edit:
I forgot to avoid gradients being propagated through `s`. The gradient computation should be done as follows:

```
     c = tape.gradient(tf.reduce_sum(z*s.numpy()), x)
```